# Observable HttpResponseError

Tags: angular, observable, httprequest, httpresponse, http-error

I'm trying to handle a HttpError or HttpErrorResponse using an observable but all I can do is handle the HttpResponse which is required but I also need to **avoid this**

[image]

I need to be able to alert the user when there is an issue with the response and maybe they could retry ...

```js
this.addService.log()
          .subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              //do something
            } else if ( event instanceof HttpErrorResponse){ 
              console.log(`couldn't httperrorresponse`)
            } else if (event instanceof ErrorEvent){ 
              console.log(`couldn't errorevent`)
            } 
    });
}
```

I have tried encasing the whole thing in a try catch but it still doesn't throw an error

Comment: You need to write the error handler in the error callback of `subscribe` because any server side error will be handled by the error callback  hence you will not get any instance of `HttpErrorResponse` in the success callback what you have written above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do it without need for creation of services... just add a comma and add an error 'subscription' I guess but every time there is an error it will be triggered... so... **happy coding breathren**

```js
this.addService.log()
          .subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              //do something
            } else if ( event instanceof HttpErrorResponse){ 
              console.log(`couldn't httperrorresponse`)
            } else if (event instanceof ErrorEvent){ 
              console.log(`couldn't errorevent`)
            }}, err=>{
                console.log(err)
                JSON.stringify(err)
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTTPInterceptor - [Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

You will have something like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService, private router: Router) { };

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      retry(1), // repeating the request one time on error
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error) {
            // Do what you want with the error
            return throwError(error); // Throw error like it normally does, without the catchError
        }
     }
  }
```

You can try to use this [tutorial](https://ivanit.eu/hobbies/article/34).